How can I set the values of a row in a pandas dataframe which uses datetime.date indexing?
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:
             EURGBP  EURCAD    GBPEUR    GBPCAD
date                                           
2018-06-22  0.87663  1.5459  1.140732  1.763458
2018-06-25  0.88040  1.5542  1.135847  1.765334
2018-06-26  0.88160  1.5549  1.134301  1.763725
2024-05-06  0.55550  0.4444  1.800180  0.800000

I am trying to set the last row to NAN values.
I should mention that the index are datetime.date types.
I can drop the last row using:
df = df.drop(index=pd.Timestamp("2024-05-06"))

I tried:
df['EURGBP'].iloc[3] = 'NAN'
df['EURCAD'].iloc[3] = 'NAN'

The first command works, but on the second one I get:
pandas.core.common.SettingWithCopyError: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy


Use df.iloc[-1] = np.nan

If need one column df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('EURGBP')] = np.nan

Wow... I've spent hours on this, and in a few seconds you have the answer. Thank you sir.
